# angular 2 get element id

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

**I have to pass the element id on focus. I tried many syntax nothing works for me.**

I cannot use @Viewchild as its dynamically created.

```
<tr *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles;let i = index;trackBy :trackByVehicles">
  <td>
  <kendo-autocomplete [data]="bookingItemRelations" 
  (focus)="relationsFocusAutoComplete({{i}})"  //Its not working.
   #relationAutocomplete{{i}} required id="relation--{{i}}">
  </kendo-autocomplete>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass without the expression

```
  (focus)="relationsFocusAutoComplete(i)"
```

**CODE**

```
<tr *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles;let i = index;trackBy :trackByVehicles">
  <td>
  <kendo-autocomplete [data]="bookingItemRelations" 
  (focus)="relationsFocusAutoComplete(i)"   
   #relationAutocomplete{{i}} required id="relation--{{i}}">
  </kendo-autocomplete>
</td>
```

Comment: How to get the element id. `i` is index here. What i expect relation1 , relation2 like that

Comment: It should return index value i , inside the relationsFocusAutoComplete you can append with relation---

Comment: @thanks, also 1 more doubt. `kendo-autocomplete` has toggle function can we trigger that on the focus event. Something like this `(focus)="toggle(true)"`

Comment: yes you should be able to do! mark if the answer help

Comment: Will do within 5 mints, there is a time for it

Comment: when `(focus)="toggle(true)` i tried its return `toggle is not a function`. its a inbuild function in the kendo.

Comment: where do you have the toggle function

Comment: the toggle is inbuild fucntion for a kendo-autocomplete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161726/discussion-between-eldho-and-sajeetharan).